# SQL counting distinct matching values

Tags: sql, sqlite

ive been struggling with this for a while:

ive got 2 tables publishers, and students.

im trying to write a query to count how many students share the postccode or "pcode" text value.
the data im using has leading leading spaces both before and after, and im meant to take care of that in query as well. another problem is that a few publishers have the same postcode once you trim those spaces from either side, so i need to count the unique trimmed publisher postcodes that are equal to trimmed student postcodes.

im getting some sort of syntax error for a closed bracket on the first line when trying the following and im really stumped

aside from the syntax error im not so certain this will work either

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(LTRIM(RTRIM(publishers.pcode)))) As pubpcode 
  FROM publishers, students
 WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM((publishers.pcode))))) = pubpcode;
```

Comment: You can use [`TRIM`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#trim) instead of composition of its L and R versions. This will be at least more readable. Also it is better to use ANSI join via [`JOIN` clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html). It is also more readable and easy to support. What about result: what is your doubt and why? Do you have result you didn't expect? It is not clear now

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT ltrim(rtrim(pubcode)),count(*) Number_of_Student
 FROM publisher p inner join students s
 on ltrim(rtrim(s.pcode))=ltrim(rtrim(pubcode))
 group by ltrim(rtrim(pubcode));
```

If you want to count unique students for each pubcode then use distinct

```
     SELECT ltrim(rtrim(pubcode)),count(distinct s.id) Number_of_Student
     FROM publisher p inner join students s
     on ltrim(rtrim(s.pcode))=ltrim(rtrim(pubcode))
     group by ltrim(rtrim(pubcode));
```

Comment: thanks, this is getting me on the right track, but for 2 separate publisher entities that share a postcode, the output for students there will be double what it should

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing `union all` and then aggregating:

```
select trim(pcode), sum(is_student), sum(is_pub)
from (select pcode, 1 as is_student, 1 as is_pub
      from students
      union all
      select pcode, 0, 1
      from publisher
     ) sp
group by trim(pcode)
```